# Make temp table permanent

Tags: sql, postgresql

For a `temp table` `temp_data` I'm just using:

```
CREATE TABLE perm_data AS (SELECT * FROM temp_data);
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this than creating a full copy of the table?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think you can change the schema.  I don't know if you can change the table type.

Comment: situation is just that I ended up with a temp table that I want to persist across sessions. I can do that with `create table as()` . Seems like there should be a more efficient way, like changing the schema somehow but a google search didn't turn up any answers so I thought it was worth posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change a temporary table into a permanent one, at least no better method than yours which copies the complete table.

Attempting to cheat PostgreSQL by altering the schema will lead to

```
ERROR:  cannot move objects into or out of temporary schemas
```